# Generate random sequence with mean, standard deviation and a specific autocorrelation in R

Tags: r, time-series, sequence

I'm looking for a way to generate a random sequence from a Gaussian distribution with a mean 0, and a specified standard deviations. I also need this sequence to have a **specified auto-correlation** from one value to the next, for example 0.9. 0.5 or -0.9. (specifically; the autocorrelation would be between `X1` and `X2`, and `X2` and `X3`, but the autocorrelation between `X1` and `X3` is unimportant.)

After a lot of searching I found this blog (https://www.getyourdataon.com/2019/05/random-autocorrelation-sequences-r.html) but that won't let me specify the standard deviation or auto-correlation. I also don't think a multivariate normal distribution is the answer, as I'm looking to generate a single vector with auto-correlation, rather than several with correlation.

The closest I got was in an answer to this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29239/creating-auto-correlated-random-values-in-r):
`x <- diffinv(rnorm(999))`
And while this would allow me to specify the standard deviation, I can not set or alter the autocorrelation (Correct me if I'm wrong!!)

Any help you can give me would be appreciated!

Comment: do you mean autocorrelation at just the first lag, or at every lag? If you want to control the autocorrelation at every lag, it's not a random sample. If it's just the first lag, then it's possible, though it might be difficult to get it _exact_. Let me know your requirements

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, I'm looking for the first lag! (I'll update the question!) Also, the autocorrelation doesn't have to be _exact_, for example, aiming for 0.9 but getting something in a range of 0.8-0.95 would still work perfect for the question I need to use it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own.

```
data <- c(rnorm(1,0,sd=2))  # Mean=0, standard deviation=2

for(i in 1:1000) { # Number of the observations is 1000

    data[i+1]<-data[i]* -0.9 + rnorm(1,0,sd=2) # -0.9 is the desired coefficient. You can change whatever you want.

}

#plot(data,type="l")
```

To check,

```
summary(lm(data[-1]~data[-length(data)]))
```

gives,

```
Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          0.06382    0.06222   1.026    0.305    
data[-length(data)] -0.90118    0.01375 -65.554   <2e-16 ***
```

**EDIT :**

With @TimothyBilton 's contribution,

The output can be rescaled to set the standard deviation as you desire,

```
finaldata = (scale(data) + mean(data))*sd
```

Comment: Hi @maydin, thank you for your reply! The problem with this solution is that the standard deviation of the final sequence is a lot larger than the standard deviation I would be aiming for. Do you know of a way to to specify the standard deviation of the "final" distribution (in this case `data`)?

Comment: @Sanne How about scaling `data` in the answer by @Maydin to have the standard deviation you require as follows: `finaldata = (scale(data) + mean(data))*sd` where `sd` is the standard deviation you require.

Comment: To correct the output of the data as you desire in terms of the standard deviation, @TimothyBilton 's solution is perfect. You can rescale the data as he suggests.

Comment: @TimothyBilton & maydin - que head slap!! Ofcourse, thank you some much for the quick answers!

Comment: @maydin would you mind terribly updating your answer with Timothy's answer so I can mark it as accepted answer?